# How to check if a folder exists in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

We use the JobDSL plugin to implement a Jenkins Seed Job.
I need to check if a folder exists in Jenkins and only create it if it doesn't.
The following code should do the job:

```
Item rootFolder = Jenkins.instance.getItem("${Config.ROOT_PATH}")
if(!rootFolder){
    ...
}
```

but I get the following error:

> Processing DSL script jenkins-files/dsl_scripts/hpp/folders.groovy
>   ERROR: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins
>   getInstance Finished: FAILURE

The seed job runs in a sandbox. It seems that I can't get an instance of the **jenkins.model.Jenkins** class without approval by a Jenkins Administrator.

- Jenkin ver. 2.164.2
- JobDSL ver. 1.43

Is there any other way to check if a folder exists in Jenkins from within a Groovy/JobDSL script?